# View controller needs: property not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a view, that I attach a controller to via controller: on create and I want to require another controller which I'd normally do using needs:. When I add that I'm getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'has' of null"

TEMPLATES:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" charset="utf-8">
    <div id="viewport">
        {{view App.playerView}}
        {{controllers.currentUser.content.name}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="player" charset="utf-8">
    <button {{action play on="click"}}>Play</button>
</script>
```

JS:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();   

App.User = Ember.Object.extend({
    name:'John'
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function() {
        this.controllerFor('currentUser').set('content', App.User.create({ name:'Jose' }));
    }
});

//Controllers
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs:['currentUser']
});

App.CurrentUserController = Ember.Controller.extend();

App.PlayerController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    isPlaying: false,
    //needs:['currentUser'], //UNCOMMENT TO BREAK!!
    play: function() {
        this.toggleProperty('isPlaying');
        alert(this.get('isPlaying'));
    }
});

//Views
App.PlayerView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName:'player',
    tagName: 'footer'
});

App.playerView = App.PlayerView.create({
    classNameBindings: ['controller.isPlaying:playing'],
    controller: App.PlayerController.create()
})
```

I've set up a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/84F9n/ (Just uncomment the line in the PlayerController)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84F9n/4/)

You can use the [`{{render}}` helper](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-render-code-helper) to render a view/controller.

From the docs:

> `{{render}}` does several things:
>
> - Gets the singleton instance of the corresponding controller Renders
> - the named template using this controller Sets the model of the
> - corresponding controller

For your example, change the `{{view ... }}` helper to use `{{render}}` instead:

```
{{render "player"}}
```

This will find the `PlayerView` and `PlayerController` and use them, similar to a route, without the actual routing part.

Comment: Great, seems to be what I needed! I updated the fiddle with final code, sorry I forgot to save the full original one :X http://jsfiddle.net/p7VL6/